# I want to display a label on another window on pressing a button

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in python 3.5. I want to display a label on another window on pressing a button. Below is the code that i am trying, but unable to achieve. Please someone help. Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def Proceed_button():
    proceed = Tk()
    Label(proceed, text="HI")

B1 = Button(root, text ="Proceed", justify = CENTER, font=("Times", "12",   "bold"), background = "yellow", command = Proceed_button).place(x=950,y=300)
```